# xtable with American format for big numbers

Tags: r, xtable

I have the following matrix

```
matrix(c(10000, 11000, 20000, 0, 4000, 5000))
xtable(x)
```

where I would like to have the numbers in this format 10'000, 11'000 etc.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

From `xtable` help:

```
x<-matrix(c(10000, 11000, 20000, 0, 4000, 5000))
require(xtable)
xtable(x)
print(xtable(x), format.args = list(big.mark = "'", decimal.mark = ","))
#% latex table generated in R 3.0.2 by xtable 1.7-1 package
#% Wed Jun 11 18:02:05 2014
#\begin{table}[ht]
#\centering
#\begin{tabular}{rr}
#  \hline
# & x \\ 
#  \hline
#1 & 10'000,00 \\ 
#  2 & 11'000,00 \\ 
#  3 & 20'000,00 \\ 
#  4 & 0,00 \\ 
#  5 & 4'000,00 \\ 
#  6 & 5'000,00 \\ 
#   \hline
#\end{tabular}
#\end{table}
```